# How to bypass RF

Tags: rf

I have built a kit set vehicle detector which has the coil wound around a steel former and buried into a driveway or road. From this coil it connects to the control gear via a three-core screened cable. The control box turns on a relay once the coil is activated. From this relay I have connected a small VHF 300 MHz transmitter board. The problem I have is the RF just obliterates the control gear and keeps it locked on.

The controller has an adjustable timing period it will stay on. The only way I have been able to overcome this is with at least five meters separation between the transmitter and the controller. Is there some way of bypassing this RF? I have tried a couple of bypass capacitors to no effect so I'm obviously not doing it correctly.

Comment: Schematics please, i.e. what is this controller, control-box, vehicle-detector. Also this VHF 300mHz transmitter board, is it something like an ASK/OOK 315MHz ISM band RF transmitter ?

Answer (score 1):

Simple solution: faraday cage. Place around you control box only; you can easily tunnel your output signal from the controller to the transmitter. Another method is to place inductors on the DC portions of your control box; inductors block RF biasing. Would need your schematics to get a better answer.

Comment: The problem is the RF from the antenna is getting picked up by the induction loop in the roadway. Using your suggestion would require putting the antenna inside the faraday cage as well and that would ... Why do you think that placing 'inductors on DC portions' (whatever they are) would help?

Answer (score 0):

1. What is the detector coil using? Very likely a low frequency, much less than 300 mHz. You can put a low pass filter between the coil and the input on the detector box, but you need to know the detector frequency so you don't disable that. But if they are really far apart any filter with a knee above 200 mHz is likely to work. If you don't mind trying over and over, just put a small series choke/shunt capacitor very close to the detector input. Calculate a resonance about 200 mHz (anything from 20-250 mHz could work). Make sure the capacitor has short leads and the choke isn't so big it has too much shunt capacitance within it. Try http://www.wa4dsy.net/filter/hp_lp_filter.html to find values (for example, .5uH/270 pF would probably work.) The link calculates pi and tee filters but you may be able to get by with a simple ell (two-component) filter (tee with output coil omitted).
2. Is your transmitter using the same power supply as the detector? Is it causing power droop on key-up? This may not be an RF problem at all.
3. Make sure your transmitter has a proper antenna. High reflected power coming back into the transmitter can cause effects (although this shouldn't be an issue at milliwatt power).

Comment: Are you referring to MHz of mHz? The link you provided doesn't support mHz frequencies and component values look strange too.

Answer (score 0):

Here are a couple references about EMI suppression that will be helpful.
http://audiosystemsgroup.com/RFI-Ham.pdf
http://www.ti.com/lit/an/snoa382/snoa382.pdf

Find some ferrite toroids (clamp on or needing a pass through winding)  that have high impedance in the 100MHz range and use those around the power and low frequency I/O conductors going into and out of the affected equipment. That alone often solves the problem.

Consider using an  "AC line filter" on the AC power feed going into the equipment if the clamp on / wind on toroids didn't help.  As this is an exterior solution look for something that is appropriate for point of use installation at the equipment or at the outlet box feeding power to it.

If needed, and feasible, use bypass capacitors such as 0.1uF radial ceramic disc between the I/O signals and their return conductor and bypassing the LVDC power lines feeding the equipment.

Often simply running the wiring better is enough of a solution either alone or in conjunction with adding choke toroids.  If there are individual signal and power wires in a cable feeding into the equipment, try twisting the wires or cable so that the parallel runs of straight and spread apart wires inside or outside of the cable are twisted and not so far spread apart.  Where possible twist and maybe zip-tie or cable clamp wires so the bunch is tight rather than spread combed apart.  If there is slack on a cable, make a relatively tight coil loop (maybe 12" or less diameter) out of the slack cable, and don't leave a lot of the slack or coiled extra cable material near the transmitter.  Tie it away from the transmitter or against some metal framing or inside a metal enclosure or whatever is applicable at your site.

If the transmitter power is adjustable, turn it down to the minimum value necessary to have a reliable link with a bit of margin for fading and variable loss.

If you can move the transmitter antenna away from the affected equipment, or you can move the affected equipment away from the transmitter, do it, though you really shouldn't have to move anything very far.  Just another 6 feet or so is often a very helpful distance that can sometimes be accommodated just by moving things slightly along mounting locations within an existing pole / mast / cabinet infrastructure.

If you are able to use a different positioning of the antenna or a different type of antenna, ensure that a null in the far field pattern and more importantly of the near field pattern if that can be determined is oriented toward your sensitive equipment.  Positioning the sensitive equipment on the other side of a "ground plane" or "refletcor" or whatever may be helpful if those are used / usable in your situation.

Sometimes installing some inexpensive hardware store  1" or finer wire "fencing" mesh around the sensitive equipment will be a solution.  It doesn't have to be a complete enclosure or very large, just enough to reflect and absorb a useful chunk of the signal interposed between the antenna and the sensitive equipment.

Often equipment powered from AC-DC power adapters has a 6' long LVDC cable or so that can be sensitive, so be sure to coil / remove slack from / put a choke on that LVDC feed.

Check the quality of the RF antenna, antenna cable connectors, crimp/solder joints in the RF cable, and make sure they are not compromised.  A bad or incorrect cable or connector can cause a resonating / leaky feed cable that can create bad EMI issues.

You could try building or buying a 50 ohm "dummy load" termination or getting a cheap VHF SWR meter that works at 300 MHz and verifying that your antenna cable and antenna are matching the transmitter if the transmitter is of a type that can be keyed on for a substantial amount of time such that you can get a stable measurement from it.  That may not be the case if it is just a modem that sends short bursts infrequently, though if that is the case, it shouldn't really be "continuously" locking your EMI sensitive equipment.
Oh anyway if you can check the SWR (YMMV) look for 2:1 or better, otherwise something is pretty marginal in your antenna / feed cable matching vs. the transmitter tuning.
If you just use a dummy load, look for the transmitter to operate "normally" but cause no interference to the other equipment.  If you get interference with the dummy load at the antenna end of the feed cable, you probably have a bad antenna feed cable or connector or installation.  If you get interference with the dummy load installed at the transmitter output before the feed cable, something is very questionable about the transmitter's installation such that it is leaking too much RF into the surroundings -- maybe the transmitter's own DC and/or AC power cable needs choking / coiling / filtering et. al.

I suspect you'll be able to solve it with cabling, chokes, better installation techniques, line filtering, and maybe a bit of antenna / shield positioning before you have need to mess with installing capacitors or test equipment or anything more complex than a 30 minute job.

Try to avoid powering the RF transmitter and other equipment from the same AC outlet or DC supply at least if you don't filter them individually.

Don't run the RF transmitter power or data cables in the same bundle as the sensor equipment.  In fact you might check out adding some metallic conduit for some of the signal or power wiring to the transmitter and/or the sensor equpment, at least for a few feet away from the transmitter and sensor location.  Don't use the same conduit for both unless you're sure the filtering is working and that it isn't a cable to cable coupling problem.

You could also consider switching RF transmitters.  There are lots of low power 2.4GHz, 915MHz, 433MHz et. al. transmitter equipment that can send signals a pretty decent distance on milliwatts of transmitter power with tiny transmit duty cycles.  There's no reason you should have to use a high power long transmit "ON" time transmitter if you are going a relatively short distance with a small data rate and the path loss isn't insanely bad due to the local environment.